# Forloops in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

My for loop for entering the K value will only put the first K value in, print the right value but will then print all zeros instead of running the nested for loop with the next K values.

My script

```
Exp1H1 = 35.6;
Exp1H2 = 24.7;
Exp2H1 = 46.8;
Exp2H2 = 37.8;
Exp3H1 = 45.7;
Exp3H2 = 36.4;
Exp4H1 = 47.7;
Exp4H2 = 39.2;

Radius = 3.75;
L = 10;

ArrayOfHeightDiff = [(Exp1H1-Exp1H2),(Exp2H1-Exp2H2),(Exp3H1-Exp3H2),       (Exp4H1-Exp4H2)];
dhdl = ArrayOfHeightDiff./L
ArrayOfDarcys = [0.29,0.25,0.26,0.23];
v_meas = ((ArrayOfDarcys.*1000)./60)./(pi*Radius^2)

K = [-0.3 : 0.1 : 0.5];

for ii = 1 : 1 : length(K)
ExportSum = ls_error(dhdl, v_meas, K(ii))
ExportSum(1,ii) = ExportSum
end

ExportSum
```

This is the function

```
function [ExportSum] = ls_error(dhdl, v_meas, K)

total = 0;           
L = length(dhdl);   

for ii = 1 : 1 : L
dhdl1 = dhdl(1,ii);
vi = v_meas(1,ii);        

yi = 1*K* dhdl1;    
partialSum = (vi - yi)^2;   
total = total + partialSum;     
end

ExportSum = total;
end
```

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: Use [MATLAB's debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to walk through your code and evaluate what is happening in each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is in this `for` loop:

```
for ii = 1 : 1 : length(K)
    ExportSum = ls_error(dhdl, v_meas, K(ii))
    ExportSum(1,ii) = ExportSum
end
```

As this loop executes it overwrites `ExportSum` with every iteration, then copies the value to the `iith` column of the vector. There's no reason to split up the lines like this, try combining them and see if you obtain the result you are expecting:

```
for ii = 1 : 1 : length(K)
    ExportSum(1, ii) = ls_error(dhdl, v_meas, K(ii));
end
```

Which returns:

```
ExportSum =

    0.5822    0.3291    0.1477    0.0380    0.0000    0.0338    0.1392    0.3164    0.5653
```

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick mark beside it. @JamesMatthews thanks!